# Next js white border around sub pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have come across this annoying problem and couldn't find a working solution anywhere. The problem is there are white borders around the page and I could not fix it. It seems like that:
[image]

This is the root layout file in /app folder:

```
export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
            </head>
            <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

This is the page.tsx file in /app folder

```
'use client';

import React from 'react';
const Page = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
    return <> {children} </>;
};

export default Page;
```

I have a DefaultPageLayout file which wraps the sub pages:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from '@mui/material';
import colors from 'src/assets/colors';

const { background } = colors;
const styles = {
    container: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        minHeight: '100vh',
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
        backgroundColor: background.default,
    },
};

function DefaultPageLayout({ children }: { children: any }) {
    return (
        <Container maxWidth={false} sx={styles.container}>
            {children}
        </Container>
    );
}

export default DefaultPageLayout;
```

I have tried to give default color to the html and body but didn't work.

```
html {
    background-color: #1a1b29;
}

body {
    color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
    background-color: #1a1b29;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(
            to bottom,
            transparent,
            rgb(var(--background-end-rgb))
        )
        rgb(var(--background-start-rgb));
}
```

What am I missing here? Can anyone help please?

Comment: Inspect the page, it might be coming from the material UI styles.